# Importing DroneKit in IronPython

Tags: c#, python-2.7, ironpython, dronekit

I need to create a wrapper between C # and Python.The main task is in the management of quadrocopter (3DR Solo) in C #.
Typically, the control of the quadrocopter (3DR Solo) is performed via DroneKit.
My searches led me to IronPython.

Can I import DronKit into IronPython?
What are the relationships between C # and Python?

Thank you for your help!